# Can a Microcontroller peripheral operate with a frequency higher than CPU Freq.?

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, avr, cpu-architecture

I wonder if a Microcontroller peripheral can  operate with a frequency higher than CPU Freq. Is that possible?

Comment: Kindly clarify what you mean, more specifically.

Comment: I mean is that possible for a  peripheral let's say SPI to operate with 48 MHz while the processor is working with 24 MHz ! The peripheral can receive data at higher rate than the process which may result in missynchronization between them ! can we , using digital design , make this happen by storing data into intermediate buffer or bank of buffers ?

Comment: @AmrAbdeen : All the information in your comment belongs in the question.  However it renders your question even further off-topic and also way too broad even for https://electronics.stackexchange.com.  I suggest you narrow your question to something more specific, and ask elsewhere; it is not a software problem.

Comment: It's not only possible but common. For instance on ATmega16U4, during sleep the CPU clock is halted, and the USB peripheral tends to run off a 48MHz clock although the CPU can't run faster than 16MHz. There's a summary of the clock domains in the "System Clock and Clock Options" chapter of the AVR datasheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely part specific - refer to the part's data sheet to reference manual.

For simple parts such as AVR, probably not (although I have not checked - there are many parts).  For parts with complex clock trees such as STM32, certainly.  For example:

[image]

In this example (calculated by ST's deprecated but still useful [clock configuration tool](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-configurators-and-code-generators/stsw-stm32091.license=1569584312459.product=STSW-STM32091.version=1.1.0.html)), the core clock is 24MHz, while the USB is necessarily run at 48MHz and the I2S at 106.5 MHz.  Note also that the I2S can be externally clocked independent of the HSE oscillator used in this example.

Comment: Avr XMEGA devices also use a PLL to generate 48MHz USB clock from 12MHz crystal.

Comment: @Rev1.0 : Yes, but not independently of the core clock which also then runs at 48MHz.  You have entirely missed the point of the question and answer.

Comment: For example, ATtiny26 has PLL to provide up to 64MHz clock to high-speed Timer1, while the core works at not higher than 16MHz.

Comment: The question is "if a Microcontroller peripheral can operate with a frequency higher than CPU Freq". Isn't that exactly the case when the "core" runs at 12MHz and the USB peripheral at 48MHz?

Comment: @AterLux that is a clearer example.  I don't think it invalidates my answer which advises checking the documentation for the specific part.  The point was to present at least _one_ example to illustrate that it was possible.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Quite possibly, it was not clear from your original comment that that was the case.  But from my quick investigation, it appeared that the PLL output drives both the core and the USB, so the core would also be at 48MHz from a 12MHz crystal.  I think it is academic, the question was whether it was possible, and the answer is _yes_, if supported by the specific part.